# What's wrong with my 'mySQL' code? Stored Procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm not sure why my code isn't giving me back results. 
This all makes sense in my head; however, when I run it, I don't get back any results or errors. I want to note as well, that I'm using MySQL Workbench.

Help? Thanks!

MySQL Code:

```
USE ap;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN _name varchar(50))
BEGIN

SELECT
    vendor_name
FROM
    vendors
WHERE
    vendor_name = _name;

END //

CALL test('ASC Signs');

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `SELECT    vendor_name
FROM    vendors
WHERE   TRIM(vendor_name) = _name;`

Comment: "No results" is a valid result if nothing is matched on the `WHERE` clause.  What is your data, what is your input, and what result are you expecting?  Have you ensured that the data is an *exact* match to the input, including whitespace?

Comment: Writing a stored procedure to run a `SELECT` is pretty heavy handed. Is there any reason you need a stored procedure at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon at the end if the `CALL test` line isn't a statement separator.
It looks like the statement delimiter is still the double slash `//`.

If this is getting submitted to MySQL server, we would expect some kind of error to be returned.  (I can't speak to how MySQL Workbench is handling it, what it's submitting to MySQL server and what its doing with the return.)

If that's the script being run, in one fell swoop, my suggestion is to

move the **`DELIMITER ;`** statement *before* the `CALL` statement.

Either that, or, end the `CALL` statement with the current statement delimiter `//`.

Comment: Oh my gosh. I feel kind of stupid right now. It's always the easy mistakes that trip us up the most.